# how to replace result urls using regex php

Tags: php

i want to parser web using simple dom ,i get output like here

my code

```
foreach($html->find('ul[class=result-topic] a ') as $e){
  $count++;


 $d = ($e->href )."<br>";




echo($d)."<br>";
if($count == 2)
{
    exit();
}
}
```

output

```
/news/354985850
/film/74808409409
```

this not full article ,how to  replace url with full article like here ,output

```
/news/full/354985850
/film/full/74808409409
```

Comment: how to insert 'full' after category(news,film...etc) ,before post id(354985850,74808409409,....etc)

Comment: how to used implode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to `explode`, append the second to last element, then `implode`.

```
$string = '/news/354985850';
$parts = explode('/', $string);
$parts[(count($parts) - 1)] = 'full/' . $parts[(count($parts) - 1)]; 
echo implode('/', $parts);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/669122

Another approach would be a regex with `preg_replace`:

```
$string = '/news/354985850';
echo preg_replace('~(.*)/~', '$1/full/', $string);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/669123

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dQJY8v/1